# How do I undo an accidental change in my view using Windows on Lenovo?

Tags: windows, user-interface, lenovo-desktop-computer

I realize that the question title is not too informative. I suppose improvements there would be welcome. One step in that direction might be the correct language for these various views I describe below.

I'm using a Lenovo Ideacentre, using whichever version of Windows came with the computer. I bought the computer new, in the fall of 2020, just a few months ago. I don't know which of these facts bear on my question.

Anyhow, until 9AM this morning, my computer’s display used to look something like this.
[image]

I literally wiped the monitor with a towel to remove dust. And now it looks very much like this.
[image]

It used to be that I could have several windows open at once, and resize them so that I could see several at once, and click into any one of them to work on that document, use that browser window, etc. At the bottom of the screen was a row of application icons, and if I hovered the pointer over one of them, a small view of open documents in that application would appear. I could select one of these small views and return to the window it represented.

But none of that is true now. Now, any open document completely fills the monitor. At the top right of the window I still see, from right to left, the X to close the document, the stack-of-squares icon that used to make the window smaller than the monitor, and the minus symbol to minimize the document. The X and the - still work, but the stack-of-squares symbol doesn’t seem to do anything at all now. And I don’t have the row of application icons at the bottom of the screen anymore.

I feel panicked, like I've returned my computer to the late 1980's. I want it to come back.

P.S. In the first picture I've tried to remove an image of an open window that was irrelevant to my question. This edit inserted a black rectangle in place of that open window. So the actual pre-9AM view should have included the same part of the colorful feather that is still visible in the second picture.

Comment: Is it Touch Screen?   (a) Static (wiping a towel across it).  Shut down normally and leave it for a couple of hours. Turn it back on.  (b) Touch screen (towel) changed settings. Go to Personalization and change the Theme to one that looks like your computer use to look. Start with these two ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have turned on 'Tablet Mode'.

To undo this, click on the search magnifying glass on the bottom left and type 'tablet settings'.

Once inside, Click on 'Change additional tablet settings' and then turn off tablet mode

[image: Tablet Settings Screen]

Comment: Hooray! Back to the future! Thanks for your help.